# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint. The conflict occurred in database

Tags: sql, database

I need help guys, im stuck on this problem. it says "
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FKAVATARS_SP146245". The conflict occurred in database "gk314", table "gk314.AVATARS", column 'avatId'.
The statement has been terminated."

this happened when I tried to run this query "INSERT INTO AVATARS_SPECIE(avatId, specieId) VALUES ('12', '312');"

Comment: Make sure you have an `avatId = 12` in the table you reference that column

Comment: Are you sure you have an avatId of  12 in referenced table?

Comment: im sorry I don't understand. could u please explain it. thanks

Comment: what do u mean by having 2

Comment: where should I put avatid = 12?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that the specieId='312' does not exist at the table of species which i suppose specieId is a primary key. So you should first insert the specieId='312' at the species table and then do your insert.